# Creating a responsive sidebar with Stimulus

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, typescript, sidebar, stimulusjs

I wrote the code for the responsive sidebar. The menu close button works, but the open button does not work.

On assignment, I have to write all this with the help of Stimulus

HTML is written in the application.html file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>CosmoPort</title>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
  <%= csp_meta_tag %>

  <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application', media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
  <%= javascript_pack_tag 'application', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
</head>

<body>
<div class="h-screen flex overflow-hidden bg-gray-100">
  <!-- Off-canvas menu for mobile, show/hide based on off-canvas menu state. -->
  <div data-controller="sidebar" class="md:hidden">
    <div class="fixed inset-0 flex z-40"
         data-sidebar-target="element"
         data-transition-enter="transition-opacity ease-linear duration-300"
         data-transition-start="opacity-0"
         data-transition-enter-end="opacity-100"
         data-transition-leave="transition-opacity ease-linear duration-300"
         data-transition-leave-start="opacity-100"
         data-transition-leave-end="opacity-0">
      <div class="fixed inset-0">
        <div class="absolute inset-0 bg-gray-600 opacity-75"></div>
      </div>
      <div
        data-sidebar-target="element"
        data-transition-enter="transition ease-in-out duration-300 transform"
        data-transition-enter-start="-translate-x-full"
        data-transition-enter-end="translate-x-0"
        data-transition-leave="transition ease-in-out duration-300 transform"
        data-transition-leave-start="translate-x-0"
        data-transition-leave-end="-translate-x-full"
        class="relative flex-1 flex flex-col max-w-xs w-full pt-5 pb-4 bg-gray-800">
        <div class="absolute top-0 right-0 -mr-12 pt-2">
          <button
            data-action="click->sidebar#toggle"
            class="ml-1 flex items-center justify-center h-10 w-10 rounded-full focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-white">
            <span class="sr-only">Close sidebar</span>
            <!-- Heroicon name: x -->
            <svg class="h-6 w-6 text-white" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
              <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M6 18L18 6M6 6l12 12"/>
            </svg>
          </button>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-shrink-0 flex items-center px-4">
          <img class="h-8 w-auto" src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/workflow-logo-indigo-500-mark-white-text.svg" alt="Workflow">
        </div>
        <div data-controller="sidebar" class="mt-5 flex-1 h-0 overflow-y-auto">
          <nav class="px-2 space-y-1">
            <%= render "layouts/application_sidebar" %>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="flex-shrink-0 w-14" aria-hidden="true">
        <!-- Dummy element to force sidebar to shrink to fit close icon -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <!-- Static sidebar for desktop -->
  <div class="hidden md:flex md:flex-shrink-0">
    <div class="flex flex-col w-64">
      <!-- Sidebar component, swap this element with another sidebar if you like -->
      <div class="flex flex-col h-0 flex-1">
        <div class="flex items-center h-16 flex-shrink-0 px-4 bg-gray-900">
          <img class="h-8 w-auto" src="https://tailwindui.com/img/logos/workflow-logo-indigo-500-mark-white-text.svg" alt="Workflow">
        </div>
        <div class="flex-1 flex flex-col overflow-y-auto">
          <nav class="flex-1 px-2 py-4 bg-gray-800 space-y-1">
            <%= render "layouts/application_sidebar" %>
          </nav>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="flex flex-col w-0 flex-1 overflow-hidden">
    <div class="relative z-10 flex-shrink-0 flex h-16 bg-white shadow">
      <button
        type="button" data-sidebar-target="element"
        data-action="click->sidebar#toggle"
        class="px-4 border-r border-gray-200 text-gray-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-inset focus:ring-indigo-500 md:hidden">
        <span class="sr-only">Open sidebar</span>
        <!-- Heroicon name: menu-alt-2 -->
        <svg class="h-6 w-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
          <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M4 6h16M4 12h16M4 18h7"/>
        </svg>
      </button>
      <div class="flex-1 px-4 flex justify-end">

        <div class="ml-4 flex items-center md:ml-6">
          <button class="bg-white p-1 rounded-full text-gray-400 hover:text-gray-500 focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500">
            <span class="sr-only">View notifications</span>
            <!-- Heroicon name: bell -->
            <svg class="h-6 w-6" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" fill="none" viewBox="0 0 24 24" stroke="currentColor" aria-hidden="true">
              <path stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" stroke-width="2" d="M15 17h5l-1.405-1.405A2.032 2.032 0 0118 14.158V11a6.002 6.002 0 00-4-5.659V5a2 2 0 10-4 0v.341C7.67 6.165 6 8.388 6 11v3.159c0 .538-.214 1.055-.595 1.436L4 17h5m6 0v1a3 3 0 11-6 0v-1m6 0H9"/>
            </svg>
          </button>

          <!-- Profile dropdown -->
          <div data-controller="dropdown" class="ml-3 relative">
            <div>
              <button
                type="button" data-target="dropdown.button" data-action="click->dropdown#toggleMenu"
                class="max-w-xs bg-white flex items-center text-sm rounded-full focus:outline-none focus:ring-2 focus:ring-offset-2 focus:ring-indigo-500 transition ease-in-out duration-150" id="user-menu" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true">
                <span class="sr-only">Open user menu</span>
                <% if current_user.photo.attached? %>
                  <%= image_tag current_user.photo.variant(auto_orient: true, gravity: "center", resize: "200x200^").processed, class: 'rounded-full h-8 w-8' %>
                <% else %>
                  <svg class="h-8 w-8 text-gray-600 rounded-full" fill="currentColor" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
                    <path d="M24 20.993V24H0v-2.996A14.977 14.977 0 0112.004 15c4.904 0 9.26 2.354 11.996 5.993zM16.002 8.999a4 4 0 11-8 0 4 4 0 018 0z"></path>
                  </svg>
                <% end %>
              </button>
            </div>
            <!--
              Profile dropdown panel, show/hide based on dropdown state.

              Entering: "transition ease-out duration-100"
                From: "transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                To: "transform opacity-100 scale-100"
              Leaving: "transition ease-in duration-75"
                From: "transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                To: "transform opacity-0 scale-95"
            -->
            <div class="menu hidden"
                 data-dropdown-target="menu"
                 data-transition-enter="transition ease-out duration-100"
                 data-transition-enter-start="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                 data-transition-enter-end="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                 data-transition-leave="transition ease-in duration-75"
                 data-transition-leave-start="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                 data-transition-leave-end="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
            >
              <div class="origin-top-right absolute right-0 mt-2 w-48 rounded-md shadow-lg py-1 bg-white ring-1 ring-black ring-opacity-5">
                <div role="menu" aria-orientation="vertical" aria-labelledby="user-menu">
                  <%= render partial: 'layouts/account_items' %>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <main
      class="flex-1 relative overflow-y-auto focus:outline-none" tabindex="0">
      <div class="py-6">
        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 md:px-8">
          <%= yield :page_header %>
        </div>
        <div class="max-w-7xl mx-auto px-4 sm:px-6 md:px-8">
          <%= render partial: 'layouts/flash' %>
          <%= yield %>
        </div>
      </div>
    </main>
  </div>
</div>

<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container mx-auto mt-5">
    &copy; <span id="current_year"></span> CosmoZoo Inc, All rights reserved.
  </div>
</footer>
</body>
</html>
```

js code written in sidebar_controller.js

```
Import { Controller } from "stimulus";

export default class extends Controller {
  static targets = ["element"];

  toggle(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    this.elementTargets.forEach((element) => {
      if (element.classList.contains("hidden")) {
        element.classList.remove("hidden");
        element.classList.add("block");
      } else {
        element.classList.add("hidden");
        element.classList.remove("block");
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Here are screenshots.
The close button works, but the menu open button does not work.
Where did I go wrong? Is the problem in the code in sidebar_controller.js or in application.html?

[image]

[image]

Help me, please.

Comment: 1. Throw in a `console.log("click")` at the top of the your toggle function to make sure the open button initiates the controller. 2. If so, put a console.log in the forEach block and another in the if...else blocks to see where it's going through. 3. Make sure you inspect the page and look at the console output. JS errors are notified there.

Comment: @sam Thank you for your feedback.
Tried as you said.
There were no errors.
Maybe the error is somewhere in application.html?

Comment: Maybe. Is it hitting the correct logs? I'm really curious if it is finding the elementTarget

Comment: @sam Only "else" works.

The "if" part doesn't work.

"hidden" is added but not removed

Comment: that means that `contains` is never hitting. Try `element.classList.value.includes("hidden")`

Comment: @sam Unfortunately it didn't help

Answer (score 0):

My Answer for anyone who faces the same issue is that somehow `stimulus-use` affect your code; I comment data-transition-*, and it works well. Also, in the controller, you don't need to add or remove class `block`.